# Notepad++ Combine Specific Line with second line

Tags: tabs, notepad++, line

I'm trying to combine every line that starts with "Text" with the second line:

```
Text 1  
    Line 1  
    Line 2  
    Line 3  
    Line 4
Text 2  
    Line 1  
    Line 2  
    Line 3
Text 3  
    Line 1  
    Line 2  
    Line 3  
    Line 4  
    Line 5  
    Line 6 
Text 4
    Line 1
    Line 2
```

And I'd like it to look like this.

```
Text 1      Line 1  
    Line 2  
    Line 3  
    Line 4
Text 2      Line 1  
    Line 2  
    Line 3
Text 3      Line 1  
    Line 2  
    Line 3  
    Line 4  
    Line 5  
    Line 6 
Text 4      Line 1
    Line 2
```

I have managed to combine them but the issue is that it removes the number, so it ends up like "Text        Line 1" instead of "Text 1      Line 1". I want to keep the tab space as well.

Comment: This isn't very useful, when there is no language tag or code to go along with it. I have no idea what you may be working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^Text.*)\R`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(           # start group 1
^           # beginning of line
Text        # literally Text
.*          # 0 or more any character but newline
)           # end group
\R          # any kind of linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Sorry for the late reply but I really appreciate what you did.